# Optimize a set of coordinates based on a cost function

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a set of (x_i,y_i) coordinates defining a path between an initial point and a final position, that I do not want to move. Right now I am optimizing the path based on distance between points (to reduce the length of the path) and curvature of the points which are included into the cost function and jacobian. The problem is that to accomplish that I have to create a state vector wit all the  stacked and find the minimum. The state space gets length 2*N where N is the number of samples that I have and it runs extremely slow even for small number of points. The layout is the following one (just including distance between points):

```
def jacobian_function(self, state_vector):
        """
        The jacobian of the cost function to be used by the optimizer
        :param state_vector : The extended state vector
        """
        gradient_array = np.zeros(len(state_vector))
        for i in range(1, int(len(state_vector) / self.num_states) - 1):  # -1 to not modify last point
            state_before = state_vector[2 * (i - 1):2 * i]
            state_curr = state_vector[2 * i:2 * (i + 1)]
            state_next = state_vector[2 * (i + 1):2 * (i + 2)]

            factor = 0.1 * 2 * (
                    state_before - 2 * state_curr + state_next)
            gradient_array[2 * i:2 * (i + 1)] += -2 * factor
            gradient_array[2 * (i - 1):2 * i] += factor
            gradient_array[2 * (i + 1):2 * (i + 2)] += factor

        return gradient_array

def cost_function(self, state_vector):
        """
        The cost function to be used by the optimizer
        :param state_vector : The extended state vector
        """
        cost = 0
        for i in range(1, int(len(state_vector) / 2) - 1):  # -1 to not modify last point
            smooth_vector = state_vector[2 * (i + 1):2 * (i + 2)] + state_vector[
                                                                    2 * (i - 1):2 * i] - 2 * state_vector[
                                                                                             2 * i:2 * (i + 1)]
            cost += 0.1 * np.dot(smooth_vector, smooth_vector)
        return cost

states = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
states_extended = np.reshape(states, states.shape[0] * states.shape[1], order='F')

result = optimize.minimize(fun=self.cost_function, states_extended, method="BFGS",jac=self.jacobian_function, options={'disp': True})
```

Do you have any idea to speed up the process while considering all the data points (normally N is around 800)?